# How to force all <div> elements to have same height in the page?

Tags: html

The following picture is my product show. I use `Bootstrap 3.2`and the whole page is within a `<div class="col-xs-12">` element and you can see the dynamically generated html code at the bottom of the image.

[image]

My problem is that the `product-container` divs don't have same heights (look at the highlighted photo).

Is it possible to fix all heights as same which doesn't affect responsiveness?

Comment: I am unsure why individuals are attempting to close this question when it is related to web design, albeit on the technical side. Reference: http://meta.webdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-topics-are-unique-to-web-design

Comment: @SlyRaskal Because many people, so many different opinions, no single rule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few lines of jQuery can solve this:

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$(".box").each(function () {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
});

$(".box").height(maxHeight);
```

(Replace `.box` with the class of the divs you want to equalize.)

Heres a quick **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvfqgkk1/1/)** to show how it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the flexbox [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) property. This makes all children have the height of their tallest sibling on that line. See it in action on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/850rtk4c/).

```
#containter { /* replace with the parent of the product-container divs */
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Unfortunately, some older browsers [do not support flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) or have different syntax. See articles on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) or [Dev.Opera](https://dev.opera.com/articles/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/#fallbacks) for how to maximize support.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class called "container" with a fixed height and apply it to those divs. The number of the height would be different for each breakpoint.

Comment: No. I'm using `container-fluid` in the website layout. I'm looking for a trick... The source of the problem is the length of product names